# How to read from text file in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I'm new to assembly. I'm trying to read from a text file, this is my code:

```
_DATI SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA' USE16

 Text_Buffer      dw ?
 filehandle       dw ?
 boolean          db 'boolean.txt',0
_DATI ENDS

_CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE' USE16
 ASSUME CS:_CODE, DS:_DATI, ES:_DATI

 ReadFile proc 
   mov ah, 3dh ;open the file
   mov al, 0 ;open for reading
   lea dx, file_name 
   int 21h 
   mov [filehandle], ax 

   mov ah, 3fh  
   lea dx, Text_Buffer
   mov cx, 1 ; Read 1 Byte
   mov bx, [filehandle] 
   int 21h

   mov bx, [filehandle]
   mov ah, 3eh ;close file
   int 21h
   ret
ReadFile endp
START:

call ReadFile

_end:

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

_CODE ENDS

END START
```

Isn't the ASCII from the file supposed to be saved in the allocated buffer (Text_Buffer)?

All I get now is some random byte saved, and for some reason, the program ends after I enter input. Can someone explain what's the problem and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's no allocated buffer `Text_Buffer` in your code (see [MCVE]), also you didn't specify which platform and assembler you are using, how you are building binary and what tools you are using to debug (most of that can be guessed from your code, but having the info in question gives us chance to cross-check, whether you are not trying to do something which will not work at all, like running this code under win64 environment, while it is 16 bit DOS code. You don't check for error after open file call. You don't show what is `file_name`, you don't show if you did set `ds` properly, etc...

Comment: You got the "minimal" part of [MCVE] well, actually too well, now make it also **complete** and verifiable: create small "main" setting up the `ds` and other vital things to be able to call `ReadFile` and show how you plan to call it .. then **verify** in debugger that it still doesn't work, and describe how it doesn't work, what did you expect, etc.. And check in debugger after [`int 21h, ah=3D`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3d.html) carry flag, which signals some error, when it is set.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning: I'm using TASM and debugging with TD. That's only a procedure in my code (I know how to call it), there was no file error (2, 5 or 12 and carry) and every variable is defined. The problem is that information from the text file (which includes a letter) is not saved well in the buffer. and when I run the program it gets input for some reason.

Comment: Can someone please send a code for that?

Comment: CF=1 means error... CF=0 is ok (then `ax` = file handle). So what did you get after open file, CF 0 or 1? (your code may be OK, it may be wrong file name, maybe you don't know that DOS doesn't support long file names, etc...) ... without full example, which other people can download + build + try + verify they hit the same problem as you this is very difficult to help.\ (if you have some doubts, whether `int 21h` in dosbox works, then I can assure you it works well, I have no problem to open files and read them)

Comment: 0, that what I mentioned in my comment. and I know that DOSBox doesn't support files with more than 8 characters. I've managed to do that with writing, so what's the problem with reading here??
I know that int 21h works...

Comment: `mov cx, 1 ; Read 1 Byte` -> so the first byte of the file is not read? Check the file content with hex view to verify what is the first byte (maybe there's UTF8 BOM, not a letter), and fill up in debugger the first byte of buffer with some other value, so you can verify the first byte did change. (also it's not very clear to me, why do you read only one byte of file)

Comment: I'm using it to pass information to another program, but it's not related to here. I read only one letter

Comment: I've tried this, the problem is that it doesn't change the value in the memory.

Comment: the code you posted looks to be correct, so unless you provide [MCVE] demonstrating your problem, I can't help you. Didn't actually try myself, but I'm 99% sure that if I will copy your code to my project and fill up the missing pieces, it will work for me (I did re-run it now in my head again, slowly and properly, and it looks to work fine).

Comment: this is the dataseg:

Comment: just [edit] your original question with full example,  nobody is going to waste time trying to assemble it from the scattered pieces all over. Also verify first that your example works, before posting it ( [MCVE] third time, did you try to understand what is described there?). ... from a quick read I don't see any problem also with data segment definition.

Answer (score 1):

I had to fix your code in question in these points:

```
 boolean        db 'boolean.txt',0
```

changed to (to have `file_name` symbol defined):

```
 file_name        db 'boolean.txt',0
```

And the "main" was not setting up `ds`:

```
...
START:
mov ax,SEG _DATI
mov ds,ax
call ReadFile
...
```

After this I compiled the code with TASM (`tasm so_readf.asm` `tlink /x so_readf.obj`, warning about missing stack reported and ignored, then `td so_readf.exe` to debug it), created file "BOOLEAN.TXT" containing two bytes 0x78 0x0A  (letter "x" with newline edited with linux text editor), and used turbo debugger to verify it works (under `dosbox` emulator).

After the "read" service the `ds:0000` memory view shows `78` "x" instead of `00` byte value, as expected.

I had problem to open the file because I created it after I already started the dosbox, so its existence was not known to the dosbox and it did report `CF=1, ax=2` after "open file" service first time. After using "rescan" command of dosbox the next debugger run did work as expected. But this problem is related only to my testing environment (dosbox under linux), if you are using different emulator or live DOS system, you may not encounter this. Also if the "boolean.txt" is created as result of other code run inside the same emulator/dosbox, the file should be visible. You can do on DOS command line "`type boolean.txt`" to see it's current content and verify it's existence.

But otherwise as expected, what you did post is correct, as long as all the prerequisites are, i.e. you have your `ds` valid, and you are in correct working directory, and you didn't run out of file handles (do you close all the files you open before?), etc.. Also while debugging under debugger, the invalid cases with wrong filename (wrong `ds`), and dosbox not aware of the file, did end correctly with CF=1 after "open file", so I could terminate the code in debugger early (as there's no error handling code, so it would do incorrect things afterwards).

Try again in debugger to identify what exactly doesn't work, and all return values from every `int 21h`, for example the "read" ones returns number of bytes read in `ax`, should be 1 in case of success.

Comment: @A.Shah so what was wrong?? I'm now confused. Did you forget to set up `ds` even in your full code, or what?

Comment: I don't really know, it happened when I used a macro. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Shah ah... macros... :D .. I always wonder why people would rather use macro than call subroutine in assembly, in my experience macros in asm makes everything worse. Except very very rare cases, where using macro makes sense, but most of the usage I see on stack overflow is making it worse for the gain of 2-5 source lines saved, which makes no sense to me (including things like microsoft's `invoke` macro, which saves quite some source and is reasonably simple, but annoys hell out of me when I find it in question, because I don't remember it from head = don't know how exactly it assembled).

Comment: @A.Shah you should still be able to use the listing file from assembler to see how it assembled exactly, and from debugger and breakpoints figure out why the original source didn't work. If you are using source versioning like git (you should), and you have the wrong version preserved in history, you may try to hunt it down now with your new experience and knowledge, ghost bugs which just "disappear" without fully understanding them are very dangerous in assembly code, they may even signal some completely different bug being "live" somewhere there, lurking for the next chance.